# I need to keep a text static, so when I run the .exe the text won't disappear (go up) no matter how much I type

Tags: c++, windows

First of all, I need this just for a program than runs in console only.

So, I need a specific text to always be displayed in the console, in the same place, no matter how much other text appears below it. It can't "go up", it has to be shown always.

I don't know if there's actually a way/command, to do that. So I figured I could just clear the console (clear the screen) and show it, repeating this multiple times. But I've read in several similar questions that doing so is not actually safe or the correct way to go, and I can't find an actual answer on why it isn't safe.

So I was wondering, first why clearing the console is not safe?
And most importantly how should I approach this?

Sorry if it's not well written, I'm a little rusty with my English.

If running it in windows compiler only.

Comment: The solution depends on what console you are using.  Different platforms have different solutions.  The library _ncurses_ is a very popular solution for controlling Linux consoles.

Comment: Reads like you are trying to do something in a specific way which is specifically not suitable for what you want to do. May I recommend to go one logical step back and instead ask for help with what you want to achieve by doing what you are asking about? This is basically the concept described here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem